# Parametrized get request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, get

How do I make an HTTP `GET` request with parameters in Ruby?

It's easy to do when you're `POST`ing:

```
  require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'

  HTTP.post_form URI.parse('http://www.example.com/search.cgi'),
                 { "q" => "ruby", "max" => "50" }
```

But I see no way of passing `GET` parameters as a hash using `'net/http'`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

def http_get(domain,path,params)
    return Net::HTTP.get(domain, "#{path}?".concat(params.collect { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.join('&'))) if not params.nil?
    return Net::HTTP.get(domain, path)
end

params = {:q => "ruby", :max => 50}
print http_get("www.example.com", "/search.cgi", params)
```

Comment: Surely there must be a more abstract way to do this, no?

Comment: I don't think there is in Net::HTTP...but you could just write a method that takes 3 parameters, the domain, path, and parameters, and returns the result, so you don't have to run the collect manually each time.

Comment: @Horace Loeb
There is no point abstracting this. It's so simple an abstraction isn't going to save you any code.

Comment: What's the point of the `reverse` here?  Given that hashes are orderless (usually), and the order of the variables on the query doesn't matter.

Comment: Instead of using `if not` use `unless`

Answer (score 87):

Since version 1.9.2 (I think) you can actually pass the parameters as a hash to the [URI::encode_www_form](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form) method like this:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
params = { :q => "ruby", :max => "50" }

# Add params to URI
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( params )
```

and then fetch the result, depending on your preference

```
require 'open-uri'

puts uri.open.read
```

or

```
require 'net/http'

puts Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Comment: remove the comma :D 
uri = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')

Comment: Note that `URI.encode_www_form(foo: "bar,baz")` produces `foo=bar&foo=baz`. If that's not what you expect, I recommend the accepted answer that uses `CGI.escape` or better yet something more full-featured like the RestClient gem.

Answer (score 21):

```
require 'net/http' require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse( "http://www.google.de/search" ); params = {'q'=>'cheese'}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path) 
request.set_form_data( params )

# instantiate a new Request object
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body ) 

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

I would expect it to work without the second instantiation as it would be the first request-objects or the http-object's job but it worked for me this way.

Comment: if you do `URI.parse( "http://www.google.de/search?q=cheese" )`, skip the badly named set_form_data, using `..::GET.new(uri.to_s)` that worked for me, without the hopeless second `new` instantiation. The net/http lib changeover is long overdue!

Answer (score 7):

```
Net::HTTP.get_print 'localhost', '/cgi-bin/badstore.cgi?searchquery=crystal&action=search&x=11&y=15'
```

or

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/cgi-bin/badstore.cgi?searchquery=crystal&action=search&x=11&y=15")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

response = http.start do |http| 
  http.request(req)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Excon](https://github.com/geemus/excon):

```
conn = Excon.new('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
conn.get(:query => { "q" => "ruby", "max" => "50" })
```

Answer (score 2):

new to stack overflow and I guess I can't comment, but @chris.moose is missing double quotes in his function def.  line 5 should be:

```
return Net::HTTP.get(domain, "#{path}?".concat(params.collect { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.reverse.join('&'))) if not params.nil?
```

or here's the whole thing redefined for copy/pasting

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

def http_get(domain,path,params)
    return Net::HTTP.get(domain, "#{path}?".concat(params.collect { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI::escape(v.to_s)}" }.reverse.join('&'))) if not params.nil?
    return Net::HTTP.get(domain, path)
end
```

<3
-mike

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the easiest way to do it

 require 'net/http' require 'uri'
 @siteurl = "http://www.google.de/search/#{@yourquery}"
define your query
 @yourquery = "whatever"



uri = URI.parse( "@siteurl" );
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path) 

# instantiate a new Request object
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new( uri.path+ '?' + request.body ) 

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

Might not be perfect but at least you get the idea.