# Fetch URL (with params) using Ruby

Tags: ruby

Could someone tell me how I can fetch (GET) a URL (with params) using Ruby? I found a bunch of examples online but I couldn't find one that explained how I can also pass the parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parametrized get request in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252210/parametrized-get-request-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this one. The solutions are here.

[Parametrized get request in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252210/parametrized-get-request-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/?test=1")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response uri
p response.body
```

There are also some other good HTTP clients or wrappers, such as HTTParty.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.get("http://www.example.com/?test=1")
p response.body
```

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following, it's pretty simple and doesn't make you build your own query string:

```
require 'net/http'
response = nil
Net::HTTP.start "example.com", 80 do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new "/endpoint"
  request.form_data = {:q => "123"}
  response = http.request(request)
end
```