# How to retrieve HTML text from Ajax loading behaviour Web page with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4848850/696088) ,I have tried to fetch HTML with ruby language from any HTML.

For any simply website is ok to use these method. But when I tried to use these to [Coursera Site](https://www.coursera.org/), the result didn't have all of the data yet. It seem they request to the datasource [here](https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list?full=1) and use some javascript to manipulate the all content.

so, **My Question. Should I need to invoke some jQuery command on rails (server-side) to extract the data when it's all complete loading?**

Note: I am quite new with Ruby on Rails, Any example source code or demo App from gitHub or anything else is really helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to need a tool that can render the JS before you try and extract the HTML. There are probably lots of options for this, the only tool that comes to mind is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless WebKit that has support for site scrapping. Check out the section on [DOM manipulation](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#DOM_Manipulation) for some ideas on what you can do with it.

Example from the site:

The following useragent.js example demonstrates reading the innerText property of the element whose id is myagent:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('myagent').innerText;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: sounds good but my point is doing on rails, not js code on client side. or do you mean i need to invoke the PhantomJS on rails? how?

Comment: You can invoke the PhantomJS from Rails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443945/running-phantomjs-from-a-ruby-on-rails-application