# Ruby on Rails net/http Post with '\r\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post, net-http

I need to post some data in Rails to an external ASP.

My curl command is working:

```
printf 'foo=bar\r\nparameter1=4711\r\nparameter2=4712' | curl --data-binary @- http://example.com/request.asp
```

How do I do this with net/http?

Its important to keep the '\r\n' between the parameters.

My coding so far:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/request.asp')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
req.set_form_data(params)
response = http.request(req)
```

How do I set up params?

I tried something like this:

```
params = {
  'foo' => 'bar\r\n',
  'parameter1' => '4711\r\n',
  'parameter2' => '4712'
}
```

But its not working. I need to encode it but how?

I tried it with the URL encoded version of '\r\n': %0D%0A but it didn't work. Is there any way to send it as binary like curl does?

Thanks.

**Edit: Thanks to your answers I found the solution:**

```
uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/request.asp')

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
req.body = "foo=bar\r\nparameter1=4711\r\nparameter2=4712"
response = http.request(req)
```

set_form_data a) encodes and b) adds "&" both nothing I needed. Setting the body directly was the solution.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252210/parametrized-get-request-in-ruby

Comment: But I don't want a GET, I want a POST

Comment: in the question he uses a `POST` request

Comment: Well, he wants a GET for his working POST. But its not related to my problem. I can do a POST, the problem is the '\r\n' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok that `\r\n` and all but the first `=` gets URL encoded in the POST data you could try:

```
params = {
   'foo' => 'bar\r\nparameter1=4711\r\nparameter2=4712'
}
```

What is the main problem, get rid of the pair separator `&` or that `\r\n` should be sent unencoded? or both?

Comment: Thanks you brought me to the right way! I post my solution into first post.

Answer (score 1):

Only part of the solution, but you can't embed escaped chars such as \r and \n in single-quote text in Ruby:

```
'I like\r\nthe newlines'  # Won't work
"I like\r\nthe newlines"  # Will work
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this info! One step in the right direction but it still misses something (not working)