# Is there a way to pass parameters and headers using Net::HTTP in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, uri, binance

I'm trying to build a small Ruby script to interact with the Binance API (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

Here is what I have so far. This is all one script, but I've broken this up into "what I think works" and "what I think is broken" sections for clarity:

**I think the includes, function, and param creation work properly:**

```
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

def params_with_signature(params, secret)
  params = params.reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }
  query_string = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), secret, query_string)
  params = params.merge(signature: signature)
end

BASE_URL = 'https://api.binance.com'
api_key = ''
api_secret = ''

params = {
    symbol: 'BNBBTC',
    side: 'BUY',
    type: 'MARKET',
    timeInForce: 'GTC',
    quantity: 1,
    recvWindow: 5000,
    timestamp: Time.now.to_i * 1000
}
```

**I think this is where things are going wrong**

```
uri = URI("#{BASE_URL}/api/v3/order")

header = {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = params_with_signature(params, api_secret).to_json
request["X-MBX-APIKEY"] = api_key

response = http.request(request)

puts response.body
```

The problem is that I keep receiving various "malformed" errors when attempting to send requests. Again, I think the problem is with the Net::HTTP post attempt above.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's a solution for you but I've rewritten your code to use `HTTParty` gem instead of `net/http`. In my opinion it's much easier to use this gem.
As a result, I've got `{"code":-2014,"msg":"API-key format invalid."}` which I think is a proper response as far I don't have API key for Binance.

```
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'httparty'
require 'openssl'

def params_with_signature(params, secret)
  params = params.reject { |_k, v| v.nil? }
  query_string = URI.encode_www_form(params)
  signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), secret, query_string)
  params.merge(signature: signature)
end

params = {
    symbol: 'BNBBTC',
    side: 'BUY',
    type: 'MARKET',
    timeInForce: 'GTC',
    quantity: 1,
    recvWindow: 5000,
    timestamp: Time.now.to_i * 1000
}

BASE_URL = 'https://api.binance.com'
api_key = ''
api_secret = ''

uri = URI("#{BASE_URL}/api/v3/order")

headers = {
  'X-MBX-APIKEY': api_key,
  'Content-Type': 'text/json'
}

response = HTTParty.post(uri, headers: headers, body: params_with_signature(params, api_secret))

puts response.body
```

Let me know if it helped you :)

For `Net/Http` soution you may look here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252210/parametrized-get-request-in-ruby`